# magento connect manager shows extension is installed but actually its not

Tags: magento

I have installed an extension , On installing it magento shows its progress in terminal properly ...
But in actually it is not installed .
Neither the extension list includes its name.
For every extension the same problem exists .
please suggest me what may have gone wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have cleaned cache from system->cache management right? Also some extensions require you to logout and login in backend otherwise they give you 404 page.

Also try to look in system->configuration->advanced->disable module output. You can see all installed extension on your installation.

Edit: also try to see in app/etc/modules if there is an xml with extension's name, and if in app/code/local or app/code/community there is a folder with all files. If there are not any, maybe it's a problem with permissions.

Try to see section "Permissions not correct/insufficient" in http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh

Comment: I have already done with all the points suggested by you ...But the problem persists ...

Comment: try to see in app/etc/modules if there is an xml with extension's name, and if in app/code/local or app/code/community there is a folder with all files. If there are not any, maybe it's a problem with permissions. Try to see section "Permissions not correct/insufficient" in http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh

Comment: Yeah . It was permission issue . . .

Comment: In this case, plesase set your question as resolved. Thank you